# redirect to 404 wildcard subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, debian, mod-rewrite, wildcard

I setup a wildcard A record on my domain registrar. Now if a user access a missing subdomain on my domain, they will be redirected to the homepage. Currently my initial setup was this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [R]
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  # more below...
</VirtualHost>
```

Any wildcard subdomain or if my IP is entered via URL will redirect to the homepage. Can I do something about this that will redirect (HTTP redirect perhaps) the wildcard subdomains to 404 page instead of to homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the RewriteEngine, and specify an empty directory as the DocumentRoot:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/empty-directory-that-i-just-created
  # more below...
</VirtualHost>
```

Since this VirtualHost uses an empty directory as DocumentRoot, Apache won't be able to fulfill any requests; it'll return 404s for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider the option of rewriting to a statuscode 403 with code [F] and having a 403 errorpage if 'a valid permanent errorcode' is the reason you want a 404 code and not exactly this code.

```
DocumentRoot /some/valid/directory
ErrorDocument 403 /nothere.html

RewriteRule /nothere.html /nothere.html [L]
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

The rewriterule for the 403 page is to avoid a configuration error.